# Spring JPA with AMQP

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, microservices

We are thinking about having a micro service architecture in our business application. We think about having the communication via ampq. With this researches that i made for that, the question comes up: How to standardise the communication while programming?
For example: If you do some database requests you can use spring-data-jpa that creates for you the code to send those requests.
Isn't there a way to use something like that for AMQP requests if you need an object from another service, something like an AMQPRepositories to have this standardised way?
Does someone has some other ideas or made some experiences with that?

Comment: I think a picture of the architecture will help

Comment: It's not about the architecture more about the programming. To have a JpaAmqpRepository or something like that

Comment: Did you need something like [this](http://projects.spring.io/spring-amqp/)

Comment: Actually not now. I just thought about some solutions on how to micro service and hoped that there could be a nice information/idea exchange about ideas and experience of other developers